# String formatting for custom classes in Python

Tags: python, oop, string-formatting

I coded a custom class `IntegerMod` for integers modulo a prime number. Everything works fine. Then used them as coefficients of polynomials built with `numpy.poly1d`, and managed to implement enough methods in `IntegerMod` so that operations with those polynomials work as I needed (for instance, finding interpolating polynomials given a bunch of points).

Just a little detail remains, it is that `print(pol)` for those polynomials actually fails, because Python tries to use string formating `%g` for the coefficents, and that fails saying `IntegerMod` should be a string or a number.
In fact `IntegerMod` inherits from `numbers.Number`, but it seems not enough. My question is, can I implement in my class the behaviour for string formatting? If not, how should I deal with this issue?

A MWE producing the error:

```
import numbers
import numpy as np


class IntegerMod(numbers.Number):
    def __init__(self, k, p):
        self.k = k % p
        self.p = p

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%d (%d)>" % (self.k, self.p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = 13
    coef1 = IntegerMod(2, p)
    coef2 = IntegerMod(4, p)
    print(coef1)  # Works as expected
    pol = np.poly1d([coef1, coef2])
    print(pol)
    """ # error:
        s = '%.4g' % q
        TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'IntegerMod'
    """
```

Comment: Why don't you implement __str__ method (keep in mind that when _str__ is missing, then print and any function using str() invokes __repr__())

Comment: Change to `np.poly1d([repr(coef1), repr(coef2)])` to get **your** `__repr__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should implement the `__float__` method, since poly1d formatting expects floats.

Something like this

```
    def __float__(self):
        return float(self.k)
```